# jQuery - can it handle 'actual' event BEFORE executing this code?

Tags: jquery, events

I'm working on a jQuery method that will get the `val()` of a text field and `show()` or `hide()` any divs with an id that matches the value of the text field.  I'd like the code to acknowledge the keystroke as part of the 'search term' but instead it is searching based on the current value of the text field, just prior to the keystroke.

Code snippet:(can provide more if crucial, but I don't believe so)

```
handleTextType: function(event){
    //change visible divs on change event
    var currentText = $(this).val().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase(); //to match id names
    console.log(event); //testing junk
    console.log(currentText); //testing junk
    infoBot.revealMatches('#'+currentText); //other method which actual does the reveal
    //can't use e.preventDefault or return false - text field won't update!!
},
```

This code is then bound to `$('myTextField').keypress()`, which is just an HTML text form.

Once I 'smart up' this method a little bit to match partial strings - ie, match div with an id of 'patients' when all I've type so far is 'pat' - this may be a non-issue, but that's an incidental fix and I'm not totally thrilled with that.  How can I get the text field's value to update BEFORE the rest of this method is called?  Is there a `super()` or something similar I can be implementing so that the actual `keypress` happens and updates the string before calling `val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have you input updated BEFORE you handler is fired just use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

Comment: Why was accepted an answer coming 7 minutes after mine and identical ?

Comment: @dystroy Maybe because at first you suggested keydown event?

Comment: You created your answer long after I fixed mine after an initial misunderstanding of the question.

Comment: @dystroy Long after?)) you see when you post an answer the author of the question doesn't refresh a page every second waiting for your fixed answer. You are like a kid, just ask Stick why and ask him to change his choice if it's so important for you )

Comment: Hum... Do you think it's right for you to abuse the fact that OP didn't refresh (contrary to you) its browser in the five minutes separing my edit from your question ? OK... but don't call other users kids because you find a trick to game the system.

Comment: @dystroy it wasn't me who marked the answer an I didn't make anything to force him do it. So you'd better think twice before accusing me. Stick please change your choice it's dystroy is very upset about the misunderstanding

Comment: @dystroy by the way I didn't steal your answer it was mine as at first you suggested keydown event and I din't see your update, you are not just the only one here who can answer to the relatively simple question

Comment: If I could accept both I would. I apologize if anyone feels slighted. I'm not certain it makes sense to complain when you already have 77k and going reputation, though.  No one's gaming anyone here, I may as well have flipped a coin, or asked my dog which answer she preferred. It's good to know that we're all united toward a common goal here, though - I'm glad that a little extra reputation generates more dialog than most questions.  Stay classy Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Stick It's not about my reputation. I'm known for making many answers CW so that I gain no reputation from them. And I point in the same way late duplicate answers when I'm not among the people answering. And never do I insult users and call them kids. I just try to make SO a cleaner and better place. But there's no reason to give this very small problem more importance that it should have, don't touch anything and let's let this discussion die.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of the `keypress` event you bind to the `keyup` event, then the value of the field is changed before your event handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTimeout with a timeout of zero to delay your code execution until after all scheduled event handlers have finished running.

As an example, see this code:

```
handleTextType: function(event) {
    var currentText = $(this).val().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase(); //to match id names
    setTimeout(function() {
        // code here to execute after all currently-scheduled
        // code (other event handlers) have been run
    }, 0);
},
```

`setTimeout()` is normally used to delay execution of a block of code for a set period of time. When called with a time of zero though, it has the practical effect of running the code as soon as everything else it's doing is finished.

Comment: Well unfortunately, `keyup` does what I needed to do, but this is worth remembering as well!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`keyup` works like the others suggested

I prefer `change` because this only fires if the actual value changes. Pressing the up/down/left/right arrows would fire `keyup`